# Why must texture samplers be uniform variables in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

To use a texture in an OpenGL shader, I have to write the Texture Unit to be used into a uniform variable:

**source.c:**

```
// Write 0 to uniform variable
GLuint texSampler = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texSampler");
glUniform1i(texSampler, 0);
```

**shader.glsl**

```
uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void SomeFunction(vec2 coord)
{
    vec4 data = texture(texSampler, coord);
    // do something
}
```

Why can't I just select the texture unit directly into the shader source, like this?

**shader.glsl**

```
void SomeFunction(vec2 coord)
{
    vec4 data = texture(0, coord);
    // do something
}
```

What is the architecturial reason, that I have to use a uniform variable to pass the texture unit into the shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I just select the texture unit directly into the shader source

[You can:](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points)

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void SomeFunction(vec2 coord)
{
    vec4 data = texture(texSampler, coord);
    // do something
}
```

Binding indices of course must be constant expressions.

As for why you can't just use a number directly... how would GLSL know what *kind* of texture you're talking about? [GLSL samplers are typed](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Sampler_types), in accord with the kind of texture being accessed. This is important, as it also changes what parameters `texture` takes. If you're accessing a 1D texture, `texture` takes a single float as a texture coordinate. If you're accessing a cubemap, it takes a `vec3`. Etc.

This is important for many reasons. One of them being that the logic for doing the fetch is often part of the *shader* itself. A shadow sampler might do the conditional logic within the shader. That wouldn't be possible if the GLSL didn't specify that it was doing a comparison test.

Note that even [bindless textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture#Purpose), where you pass an integer that represents a texture object to the shader, still requires that you [convert the integer handle for the texture into a specific sampler type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture#Handles_as_integers).